# Trying to access local file in Meteor app, but cannot fire document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

Tags: cordova, meteor

Trying to access the file system in a basic Meteor app with Cordova plugin.

Setup as follows:

Create project command: meteor create file2

Added Cordova plugin, command: meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1

However, 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
is not firing.

The Javascript console displays:
Issuing deviceready from Meteor.startup

Here is my code in main.js:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
    console.log('deviceready completed');
    getPFile();
}

Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log('Issuing deviceready from Meteor.startup');
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function getPFile() {

   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

       console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
       fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

           console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
           writeFile(fileEntry, null);

       }, onErrorCreateFile);

   }, onErrorLoadFs);
}
```

I also tried inserting:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js">
</script>
```

in main.html, but JavaScript console then shows error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

in Cordova.js

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the addEventListener statement by adding parentheses following onDeviceReady, which now calls the function onDeviceReady function, instead of just referring to the function, as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
```

However, I realized this calls the function before the deviceready event is satisfied. So, I am still trying to find out why device ready is not firing.